# Is the text in the calendar's month view supposed to be readable?

Tags: calendars

The month view in the Calendar on my device looks something like this:
[image]

On my device (HTC Titan, one of the larger WP handsets) I can only see teeny tiny text inside each day and there's no pinch/zoom so there's no way at all for me to make use of that information. It *appears* to represent the actual live content of my calendar (though it's hard to be sure), so it would definitely be useful if it was even only slightly larger.

Is my experience (unreadable month view text, with no zoom) standard across all Windows Phone devices? Is there a way for me to enlarge it that I haven't figured out?

Comment: I hate the way month calendar doesn't use all available space on screen.

Comment: True. Even in landscape mode.

Comment: How is this a constructive question? Is there a problem to solve here? It comes across like a gripe to me

Comment: @Joe rereading it i could see what you meant. i've rephrased it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The texts aren't from your calendar. They use more lines to show whether you are busy that day or not. These are the texts used in the month view:

- Dignis milt
  *Worthy of milt.*
- Nulla facilis
  *There are no easy ones.*
- Aliquam sodale
  *A member*
- Nam rhoncus nis
  *For the work*
- Nam nec vulputate
  *For the builders*
- Hello from Seattle
  *Hello from Seattle*
- Suspendisse egetos
  *We suffer*
- Maecenas sem mattis
  *Read more here*
- Clas aptent tacitis
  *And drive the fleet of silence*
- Vestibulum imperdiet
  *Your event*

Comment: Corrected some misread Latin words and translated them into English.

Comment: +1. I had no idea this is what they said! I thought they just scaled down the text on my appointment

Comment: @Joe me neither! this answer was a small and slightly strange revelation

Comment: Thanks, MS really should make the zoomed out view more usable.  Some latin text at excruciatingly small font is a very poor UI.

Comment: There's something funny about the Latin in that sixth phrase.

Answer (score 3):

The entries you see are markers for calendar entries, the more events on a day the more markers you will see in that cell.

The text in the cell is not derived from the calendar entry, and there's no way to enlarge it.   The actual text seems to be picked at random from a small set of strings that it uses to draw the screen, e.g. 'Lorum ipsum' type text.

If you look very closely, one of the strings says "Hello from Seattle"

Answer (score -4):

You CAN enlarge the text, just take a screenshot and open it in the Photos app :)